# Reset admin password for MySQL and Plesk on CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, plesk

I have updated mysql using...

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm
yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community
yum-config-manager --enable mysql55-community
yum update mysql-server
```

Everything went fine. But then when I tried to update the tables etc with

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

I got

```
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I tried

```
mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p
```

and

```
mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

after reading that this was what was needed for Plesk, but it had the same result.

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --auto-repair
```

gave

```
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

At this point I checked passwords but I thought they were correct.

At this point I messed up when trying to change/update/reset the password in mysql. I followed code I found online...

```
cp /etc/psa/.psa.shadow /etc/psa/.psa.shadow.bak # just backup
chmod 400 /etc/psa/.psa.shadow.bak # just secure backup
echo "PLACE PLAIN PASSWORD OF MySQL user ADMIN HERE" > /etc/psa/.psa.shadow
```

and also

```
mysql -uadmin -p'cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow' mysql -e "update user set Password=password('password') where User='admin'; flush privileges;"
```

And now I have

```
Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Error code: 1045) (Abstract.php:69)
```

when trying to connect to Plesk.

So I think now my mysql admin password and password in /etc/psa/.psa.shadow do not match? I have been trying to find how to start again by setting a mysql admin password and the same for /etc/psa/.psa.shadow, but at this point I decided to ask for help!

Is there anybody who can help me? :)

Comment: Ok I managed to solve it myself...

First I reset the admin password in mysql using [link] (http://www.dotkam.com/2007/04/10/mysql-reset-lost-root-password/)

Then I input the same password to the /etc/psa/.psa.shadow file by following the instructions here - [link] (http://blog.serverbuddies.com/how-can-i-changerepair-my-admin-account-if-the-password-in-plesk/)

So thats good. However, now I'm back to the original problem... when i try to run `mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p` i get the same error described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I think now my mysql admin password and password in /etc/psa/.psa.shadow do not match?

Yes, you are right.

You can just set password for MySQL's admin user back from /etc/psa/.psa.shadow like:

```
mysql -uadmin -pYouCurrentPassword -e "update user set Password=password('string from .psa.shadow') where User='admin'; flush privileges;"
```

After this it's should be possible to login to plesk and change password to new one if you need.

Comment: I may be being stupid but after trying this code it's just giving me the > greater than prompt

Comment: So that way didn't quite work, but i managed to log into mysql with the admin password i had. I then did as you said, updating the admin password with the string from .psa.shadow.

However it didn't work, and also now I can't log back into mysql!

Comment: You can log into MySQL as you do it befor with: mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`

Comment: If Plesk still can't connect to MySQL please contact Plesk support.